# I keep getting the error 'Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField?' to expected argument type'Date'

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to get the persons "age" filled in a text field from user input birthdate (text field) and user Calendar.

```
    var startDate = birthDate
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"
    let currentDate = Date()
    let userCalandar = Calendar.current
    let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .month, .year])
    var age = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: startDate, to: currentDate) (error is here)
```

Thanks for your thoughts

Andrew

Comment: Hold the Option key and click on `startDate` and `birthDate`. Why type do you get? My guess is `birthDate` is a `IBOutlet`

Comment: At the very least you probably want `birthDate.text` to get the text from the text field, and then you will need to use `DateFormatter` to attempt to parse that text into a `Date`. A `UIDatePicker` is probably a better control to use than a text field.

Comment: You are correct the IBOutlet is birthDate

Comment: Ok I will try to change to birthDate.text.

Comment: startDate is a String? So how do I change this to get it to use the input from the birthDate field?

Comment: Now the error states Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Date'

Comment: and when I change the start date to a UIDatePicker the error changes to:  Cannot convert value of type 'UIDatePicker?' to expected argument type 'Date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
        let textInput = birthDate.text
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-YYYY"
        let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: textInput!)
        let currentDate = Date()
        let components = Set<Calendar.Component>([.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .month, .year])
        let age = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: startDate!, to: currentDate)
```

Comment: Thanks schtipoun, it got rid of the error now to find out why it crashed when I ran it. Says found nil while trying to unwrap an optional. I will get back to you when I try to find out what caused it. Thanks again for everyones help as this does not come easy to me.

Comment: Did you enter a date in the textfield in the exact same format you put in the dateFormatter? Like 08-10-1985. Because I ran it here and got "year: 32 month: 10 day: 17 hour: 1 minute: 8 second: 21 isLeapMonth: false" as a result of "age"

Comment: So after looking at the error, it is showing 'nil" when i hover over startDate even though I did type in the birthdate in correct format.

Comment: So definitely, you entered the date badly. The result of startDate is nil because the format of the date you input is different from dd-MM-YYYY

Comment: for some reason startDate is not receiving the textInput when added at the birthDate field

Comment: And if you do a print(textInput) just above let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: textInput!), what's the result in the console?

Comment: So i am so used to entering birthdate as 12/20/1985 where it should be 20/12/1958 the way it is formatted. Thank you for all your help

Comment: perfect 20/12/1985 is in the console

Comment: yes it is thank you and I checked your solution off as the correct answer